# How to validate push key firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a list of patients and I know the push key from               `getRef(position).getKey().toString()` using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

I am able to validate a user. I also want to check if some push key is matching the current one I have and allow the read and write for that validated user only.

Data example:

```
{
   "PatientsVisits":{
      "1jTKH4X2rDUawNLcqDJYhtECKMD2":{ // User ID
         "-KctlNc75065wZRsB7R3":{ // Push key
            "visit":{
               "drungNmae":"Shit",
               "endDate":"03/11/2017",
               "schedule":"Daily",
               "startDate":"02/02/2017"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Rules:

```
{
   "PatientsVisits": {
      "$uid": {
        "$pushkey": {
          "visit": {
             ".read":"auth.uid == $uid",
             ".write":"auth.uid == $uid"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

What would be a possible solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to validate. The key is available in `$pushkey`, but what do you want to compare it against?

Comment: Hi, Frank van Puffelen, thanks for replying.

Comment: I have a user and a patient ids. What I ‘m trying to do is something like this: if user is auth they can read PatientsVisits and can only read a specific patient node if the $pushkey matches the one under $uid. I hope it’s clear now. One more question. is it possible to authenticate Admin users using firebase on android? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [link] (http://imgur.com/a/qBNW9)